# can React native use JavaScript remotely?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to React Native, and I understand React Native injects JS to a JavaScriptCore. By looking at the examples or new react app, I can see the JavaScript is hosted in localhost:8081. In release/prod version, JavaScript files shipped within the app.

Can React Native use some JavaScript(React JS) from server in production? (like WebView which can load any html locally and remotely)

It would be great if we can deploy new UI without App release.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Its possible to update new UI without App release in React Native.

We need to use [react-native-code-push](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push) library to enable dynamic app update.